# A different notion of a decomposable symmetric tensor (besides Veronese)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, tensor-products, symmetric-spaces, tensor

$\DeclareMathOperator{\complex}{\mathbb{C}}$
Let $\bigvee^m(\complex^n)\subseteq (\complex^n)^{\otimes m}$ denote the space of symmetric tensors, i.e. the set of $x \in (\complex^n)^{\otimes m}$ that are invariant under permutations of the $m$ factors. The (cone over) the Veronese variety of $\bigvee^m(\complex^n)$ is the set of tensors of the form $x^{\otimes m}$ for some $x \in \complex^n$. This is one notion of the *decomposable tensors*.

Another notion is the set of tensors in $\bigvee^m(\complex^n)$ of the form $x_1 \vee \dots \vee x_m$, where $x_i \in \complex^n$ for all $i \in \{1,\dots, m\}$, and
\begin{align}
x_1 \vee \dots \vee x_m :=\sum_{\sigma \in S_m} x_{\sigma(1)}\otimes \dots \otimes x_{\sigma(m)}.
\end{align}

Does this latter set have a name? Does it form an algebraic variety (like the Veronese does)? If so, what is its dimension, and have its secant varieties been studied?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by $(\mathbb{C}^n)^{\otimes m}$ here? (I'm not sure I know what the "m-factors" of a generic element of $(\mathbb{C}^n)^{\otimes m}$ are, but perhaps I'm just naive). Also, I think the $S_n$ in your definition of $x_1\vee \dots \vee x_m$ should be an $S_m$.

Comment: Ah - you fixed the $S_m$ :)

Comment: @DCM Yes, thanks! I'm not sure what the ambiguity is with $(\mathbb{C}^n)^{\otimes m}$. I mean the $m$-fold tensor product of $\mathbb{C}^n$, as a vector space.

Comment: This is probably me being dumb, but... how does one define the $m$-factors of $\sum_{i\in I} x_{i_1}\otimes\dots \otimes x_{i_n}$ for an arbitrary finite $I$?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... Have you replaced $m$ with $n$ for a reason? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Tensor_powers_and_braiding

Comment: Re. $m$ and $n$: no that's a typo. Sorry! Re. what I'm getting at: how do you define the '$m$-factors' of an arbitrary element of the tensor product? (they aren't all of the form $x_1\otimes \dots \otimes x_m$). Note: this is possibly me just being ignorant, but it's possibly worth clarifying.

Comment: Let's stick to two spaces: $V \otimes W$ is defined as the free vector space spanned by $(v,w)$ for all $v \in V$ and $w \in W$, quotiented by relations like $(v,w+u)=(v,w)+(v,u)$ that make $(\cdot, \cdot)$ into a bilinear map. This quotient space is $V \otimes W$ and the equivalence class of elements of the form $(v,w)$ is referred to as $v \otimes w$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product

Comment: It's worth noting that $\mathbb{C}^n \otimes \mathbb{C}^m$ is isomorphic to the vector space of $n \times m$ matrices, with the elements of the form $v \otimes w$ mapping to the set of rank-one matrices.

Comment: The notions of rank and (border rank) for the two definitions are related and were conjectured to be the same (Comon Conjecture). However, this has been disproved https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.08740

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam I thought Comon's conjecture was that the tensor rank and Waring rank of a symmetric tensor agree? For tensor rank, the decomposables are $x_1 \otimes \dots \otimes x_m$. For Waring rank, the decomposables are $x^{\otimes m}$. Neither are $x_1 \vee \dots \vee x_m$.

Comment: symmetrize post decomposition

Comment: Good point, so the $x_1 \vee \dots \vee x_m$ rank is at most the tensor rank (and also the Waring rank). I'm pretty sure that all three of these ranks can be different, though.

Comment: The $x_1\vee\cdots\vee x_m$ is the tensor rank, whereas the $x^{\otimes m}$ is the Waring rank.

Comment: $x_1 \vee x_2=x_1 \otimes x_2 + x_2 \otimes x_1$ is often tensor rank 2, but clearly has rank 1 with respect to the notion I am asking about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your $\vee$ is essentially multiplication of polynomials. The variety of tensors $x_1 \vee \dotsb \vee x_m$ corresponds to polynomials that factor as products of linear factors. Points of the (projective) variety correspond to hyperplane arrangements. Dually, they correspond to *cycles* of $m$ points (in the dual projective space).

This variety has various names including the **Chow variety**, the **variety of completely decomposable forms**, and the **split variety**. For example [Hirotachi Abo](https://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/%7Eabo/Research/Papers/split.pdf) calls it the "variety of completely decomposable $d$-forms" (his $d$ is your $m$) and denotes it $\operatorname{Split_d}(\mathbb{P}^n)$ (also, his $n$ is your $n+1$). [Douglas A. Torrance](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.05546.pdf) calls it the Chow variety and uses the same notation, $\operatorname{Split_d}$. [Yongui Guan](https://www.math.tamu.edu/%7Ejml/tamuthesis_YonghuiGuan.pdf) calls it the Chow variety and denotes it $\operatorname{Ch}_d$. There are plenty, plenty more references which you can find by searching for those terms.

And it is indeed a variety. If you buy the correspondence with zero-dimensional cycles, that's pretty clearly closed–the points might move around and collide, but it's still a zero-cycle. If you want the equations, [Guan](https://www.math.tamu.edu/%7Ejml/tamuthesis_YonghuiGuan.pdf) seems to have some information; that's just what I found online. Better references would be [Gelfand-Kapranov-Zelevinsky](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1264417) and [Landsberg's book](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2865915) if you have access to them.

Rank with respect to this variety is called Chow rank, split rank, decomposable rank, etc. [Catalisano, et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.07789) say that for a monomial $M$, an $M$-decomposition of a form $F$ (where $\deg(F)=\deg(M)$) is an expression for $F$ as a sum of terms given by evaluating $M$ at linear forms. Waring rank is $x_1^d$-rank, and Chow (or split, or decomposable) rank is $(x_1 \dotsm x_d)$-rank.

If I may also respond to one of the comments: Indeed, Comon's conjecture was that the rank and symmetric rank of symmetric tensors would be equal. Symmetric rank is the same as Waring rank. [Shitov](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.08740) gave a counterexample to that conjecture. The analogous conjecture for border ranks, that the border rank and border symmetric rank (border Waring rank) of a symmetric tensor are equal, seems to be still open (as far as I know, as of September 2020).